# How to search a treenode text similar to Outlook in c#.net ?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on C#.Net project with infragistics tool. In my project i want to implement search options, like Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 search functionality.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Implementation of the search alogrithm, or the GUI part of it - retrieving input and presenting of search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illustrating an example using System.Windows.Forms.TreeView. Assuming the same could be done for Infragistics tree view. The key is using recursive methods when working with trees:

```
    // Returns the node with the first hit, or null if none
    public TreeNode Search(TreeView treeView, string text)
    { 
        return SearchNodes(treeView.Nodes, text);
    }

    // Recursive text search depth-first.
    private TreeNode SearchNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string text)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.Text.Contains(text)) return node;
            var subSearchHit = SearchNodes(node.Nodes, text);
            if (subSearchHit != null) return subSearchHit;
        }
        return null;
    }
```